# Higher Order Voronoi Diagrams in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, voronoi

MATLAB has an excellent function, [voronoi/voronoin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/voronoi.html) for drawing first order Voronoi diagrams. Unfortunately, there is no built in option for higher order diagrams. I understand in principle how to obtain higher order diagrams, but the implementation in MATLAB seems messy. Does anyone know of an easy way to do this in MATLAB?

Preliminary searches yielded no MATLAB-language-specific implementation (although there is some good [abstract implementation](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/ImprovedAlgKthOrderVoronoi.pdf) material).

This strikes me as odd that something so useful as a kth-order V. diagram is not "out of the box" implementable in MATLAB so I thought I would check with the experts first to see if I'm just not missing something... before I spend an untold number of hours reinventing the wheel.

P.S. There are two other questions in Stack Exchange that I've found regarding this subject with no resolution. The participants actually "gave up" in trying to figure it out. Is this really that difficult of a question?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a little example of higher order voronoi diagram from this website:http://www.nirarebakun.com/voro/ehivoro.html. Basically the idea is to use a counter. Or maybe you can look into a power diagram. It seems to use a similar algorithm:https://github.com/ArlindNocaj/power-voronoi-diagram.